# Execution failed for task ':sms:verifyReleaseResources' and Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException on Flutter app build

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey I am facing an issue building my app as release.
The error only came when I try to build the apk as a release I can debug it and I can build the app as debug I tried changing compileSDKVersion to 28 and targetSdkVersion also to 28

Here's the response that I get on `flutter build apk --release` commande.

> flutter build apk

```
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:15: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
                                 ^
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ActivityCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:17: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
                                 ^
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerFileProvider.java:3: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
                                 ^
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerFileProvider.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
public class ImagePickerFileProvider extends FileProvider {}
                                             ^
  symbol: class FileProvider
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerPlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
                                 ^
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 2342;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA = 2343;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2344;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_IMAGE_PERMISSION = 2345;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_VIDEO_FROM_GALLERY = 2352;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO_WITH_CAMERA = 2353;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_VIDEO_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2354;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_VIDEO_PERMISSION = 2355;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting final String fileProviderName;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:164: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerPlugin.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerPlugin
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
            return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permissionName)
                   ^
  symbol: variable ActivityCompat
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {permissionName}, requestCode);
            ^
  symbol: variable ActivityCompat
C:\Users\iAbdou\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:140: error: cannot find symbol
            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, fileProviderName, file);
                   ^
  symbol: variable FileProvider
20 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':image_picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     193.4s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the
incompatibility.
Building plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    0.6s

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)


The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built due to the issue above.
```

My Flutter Doctor response.

> flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.43.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found
```

issues in 2 categories.

Comment: did it run in debug mode ?  try using different version of image_picker

Comment: Hey, i am getting same issue, did you solve it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

On the file `gradle-wrapper.properties`, I changed:

<s>distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip</s>

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip

then please try `flutter clean` then run